# How do I access an in-memory database using Sequel.sqlite?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel, in-memory-database

I am accessing the in-memory database using Sequel in a Sinatra application. I want to access the in-memory database used in my application from the command line on my local host, as well as Heroku.

Is there a way to access the in-memory database outside the application or do I have to use a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [in-memory database](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) resides in your process's memory and is not accessible from outside the application.